# I want to move the Gameobject on y-axis only when I hit space key

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

The idea is to make the object ascend from the ground like a helicopter. 
The way I was tackling this by saving the transform.position.y into a y variable but its showing error when I am using transfrom.translate to change its position.
Here is the code I am using. Please help

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement: MonoBehaviour
{
[SerializeField] private float _speed = 5;

void Start()
{
    transform.position = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
}

void Update()
{
    Movement();
}
public void Movement()
{
    float y = transform.position.y;
    float horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float HorizontalInput = horizontalInput * _speed * Time.deltaTime;
    float verticalInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    float VerticalInput = verticalInput * _speed * Time.deltaTime;

    transform.position = transform.position + new Vector3(HorizontalInput, y, VerticalInput);
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        y = transform.Translate(Vector3.up * _speed * Time.deltaTime);
        y++;
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you might be getting confused over what `Transform.Translate` does, as it doesn't return any value, like your code would suggest it does.

---

Here's two different usages for it:

**Using a vector:**

> ```
> public void Translate(Vector3 translation);
> ```
>
> Moves the transform in the direction and distance of `translation`.

**Using x,y,z:**

> ```
> public void Translate(float x, float y, float z);
> ```
>
> Moves the transform by `x` along the x axis, `y` along the y axis, and `z` along the z axis.

From:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Translate.html

---

Here's one way you can fix your code.

```
public void Movement()
{
    float x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * _speed * Time.deltaTime;
    float y = 0;
    float z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * _speed * Time.deltaTime;

    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        y += _speed * Time.deltaTime;
    }

    transform.position += new Vector3(x, y, z);

    // or use:
    // transform.Translate(x, y, z);

    // or use:
    // transform.Translate(new Vector3(x, y, z));
}
```